# hibernate transaction causes commit and subsequent rollback in mysql innodb

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.3.2 and mysql 5.0.77 (innodb engine).
whenever i perform any sql operation select,update etc. it causes a rollback at mysql end.(by queryin com_rollback column, i see it incrementing everytime). I do these operations in a hibernate transaction. Hibernate does not throw any exception and gracefully completes without any error.When i enabled the general log file at mysql end ,i saw following steps happening for each transaction :
set autocommit =0
execute query(select,insert,update)
commit
rollback
autocommit=1

I dont understand why a rollback is happening at mysql end after commit. no error at application log as well as mysql log. :(.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hibernate flush mode or things like that. See what i wrote here:
[migrating from HibernateTransactionManager to JpaTransactionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503820/migrating-from-hibernatetransactionmanager-to-jpatransactionmanager/8506074#8506074)

Notice that i talked about the spring @Transactionnal(read-only=true)
It not only set the flush mode to never. 
http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html

> if the transaction is marked as read-only, Spring will set the Hibernate Session's flush mode to FLUSH_NEVER, and will set the JDBC
>   transaction to read-only.

I don't know if you are using spring anyway but perhaps it is. 
If you have an hibernate session in never flushmode you perhaps have that problem.

---

If it is not the problem you may try to put a breakpoint in your jdbc driver on:

```
Connection.setReadOnly(boolean)
```

Comment: I am not using Spring . I set the flush mode to flush_never but still it comes.session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.NEVER);
   trx = session.beginTransaction();
   retObj = (T)session.createCriteria(clazz).add(
     Expression.eq(property, filter)).uniqueResult();

  } catch (HibernateException ex) {
   LOG.finer("hibernate exception :{0}",ex);
   //trx.rollback();
   throw new CpFaultException(clazz.getName(),ex);
  }catch(Exception e){
   LOG.finer("exception occured while retrieving:{0}",e);
   //trx.rollback();
  }finally {
   HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
  }

Comment: Hard to read, you'd better edit your post. I didn't say to put the session in flushmode never. Perhaps you should try to put in AUTO or ALWAYS but i don't think it is the problem... you'd better put a breakpoint in Connection.setReadOnly(boolean) and check which classes call that method